# Call to get XML element returns null

Tags: java, xml

I have a series of XML files I am looking through and grabbing a specific element from.

```
 <key>A</key>
```

I'm using this snippet of code to grab the XML element, but it returns null instead of the element I am looking for. I am not able to change the XML files.

```
    File key = new File(filePath);
    PrintWriter keyWriter = new PrintWriter(key);

    File xmlFile = new File(configPath);


    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder(); 
    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
    NodeList nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("key");


    Element keyValue = (Element) nodes.item(0);
    keyWriter.println(keyValue);
    keyWriter.close();  
}
```

I've tried using the document method as well as the apache xmlconfiguration and getElementbyId but all have returned null so far.

Comment: Can you show the actual XML, perhaps with namespaces?

Comment: is `key` root element ?

Comment: Unable to due to various NDA / confidentiality stuff. The snippet I posted is how it appears in the XML - not part of any higher level element.

Comment: *"Unable to due to various NDA / confidentiality stuff."*  Well create a test file that you *can* show us!!  If your problem description is accurate, it should be *easy* to create an SSCCE!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your code that your passing the element object to the writer's `println` function as in:

```
keyWriter.println(keyValue);
```

This will print a null value in the file. Try replacing it with:

```
keyWriter.println(keyValue.getTextContent());
```